# What matrices fulfill trace$(A^2)=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, trace, bilinear-form

I am looking for real $n \times n$ matrices such that trace$(AA)=0$.

So far I have found out that

$A^2=BC-CB$ for some $n \times n$

The nullspace of trace is generated by $\{E_{ij} | i \neq j\} \cup \{H_{i,i+1} | 1 \leq i \leq n-1\} $ where $E_{ij}$ is the $n \times n$ matrix with $a_{ij}=1$ and $0$ elsewhere and $H_{ij}=E_{ii}-E_{jj}$, the dimension of the nullspace is $n^2-1$, so these matrices are the basis of the nullspace.[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158041/dimensionality-of-null-space-when-trace-is-zero?rq=1)

However I am stuck figuring out how to relate that to $A^2$. I welcome any hints!

Comment: Those matrices do not form a subspace.

Comment: Not sure what I was thinking. Deleting that.

Comment: Is it correct to say that it is a set of subspaces?

Comment: Well, it is a cone, so it is the union of lines (which are subspaces).

Comment: How do you know its a cone? What do you mean by a cone of matrices?

Comment: If $\operatorname{tr} A^2 = 0$ then $\operatorname{tr} (\lambda A)^2 = 0$ for all $\lambda >0$.

Comment: possibly of interest to you:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506962/expressing-the-trace-of-a2-by-trace-of-a