# 'elementary' proof that all matrix with zero trace has the form $AB-BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to prove the fact mentioned in the title **without** using the theory of lie algebras?

For the record, though questions about this fact has **indeed** appeared in MSE several times, yet up til now, I think no one has given any 'elementary'(only use linear algebra) proof of this fact on MSE. So it's not a duplicate.

Any reference or answer would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

P.S. this question is **not** equivalent to this:

[If $V_0$ is the subspace of matrices of the form $C=AB-BA$ for some $A,B$ in a vector space $V$ then $V_0=\{A\in V|\operatorname{Trace} (A)=0\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181430/if-v-0-is-the-subspace-of-matrices-of-the-form-c-ab-ba-for-some-a-b-in-a-v)

or this:
[Dimensionality of null space when Trace is Zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158041/dimensionality-of-null-space-when-trace-is-zero)

Comment: The abstract of [this](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/trace0.pdf) document claims to prove it in elementary form.