# Proof that there's only one function that satisifes the properties of a trace.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, reference-works

I've been reading *Mathematics for Machine Learning*, by Deisenroth, Aldo Faisal and Cheng Soon Ong, and it contains the following lines about the trace of square matrices that I need help with:

> The trace satisfies the following properties:
> $\cdot$ tr$(A+B)$ = tr$(A)$ + tr$(B)$
> $\cdot$ tr$(\alpha A)$ = $\alpha$tr$(A)$
> $\cdot$ tr$(I_n)$=$n$
> $\cdot$ tr$(AB)$ = tr$(BA)$

> It can be shown that only one function satisfies these four properties together - the trace (Gohberg et al., 2012)

Now I can see how the 4 properties hold, based on the trace being the sum of diagonal entries of a square matrix, but the trouble I'm having is in the last line which states that it can be shown that no other function satisfies these properties. I'm unable to find a proof of the same and was hoping someone could help me with it here. I'm also not quite clear on what work the authors are referring to as *Gohberg et.al, 2012*, so some info or links on that would be really helpful too.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\Psi\colon\Bbb R^{n\times n}\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ be a map such that those four properties hold. The first two properties tell you that $\Psi$ is a linear map. The fourth property tells then you that $\Psi(M)=0$ when $M$ can be written as a linear combination of matrices of the form $AB-BA$. It is not hard to prove that [the vector space $V$ spanned by the matrices of that form is the space of those matrices whose trace is $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158041/dimensionality-of-null-space-when-trace-is-zero). But $\Bbb R^{n\times n}=V\bigoplus\Bbb R\operatorname{Id}$. In other words, any matrix $M\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ can be written in one and only one way as a sum $M_0+\lambda_M\operatorname{Id}$, with $\operatorname{tr}(M_0)=0$ and $\lambda_M\in\Bbb R$. But then$$\Psi(M)=\Psi(M_0)+\lambda_M\Psi(\operatorname{Id})=n\lambda_M=\operatorname{tr}(M).$$

Besides, my guess, is that reference to *Gohberg et.al, 2012* means the textbook *Traces and Determinants of Linear Operators*, by Israel Gohberg, Seymour Goldberg, and Nahum Krupnik, published by Birkhäuser. Anyway, take a look at the bibliography of *Mathematics for Machine Learning*.

Comment: I appreciate your answer @JoséCarlosSantos, but unfortunately, I' not too familiar with the following notation: $\Bbb R^{n\times n}=V\bigoplus\Bbb R\operatorname{Id}$. Could you maybe point me towards some resources where I can learn about it? Thank you!

Comment: That notation means that any element of $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ (that is, any $n\times n$ matrix) can be written in one and only one way as the sum of an element of $V$ with an element of $\Bbb R\operatorname{Id}=\{\lambda\operatorname{Id}\mid\lambda\in\Bbb R\}$. In other words, $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ is the direct sum of $V$ and $\Bbb R\operatorname{Id}$. You can learn about it from any Linear Algebra textbook.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Let $e_{i,j}$ be the $n$ by $n$ matrix with $1$ at the $(i,j)$ entry and $0$ elsewhere, and similarly let $e_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ have $1$ in the $i$-th component and $0$ elsewhere. Note that $e_{i,j} = e_i e_j^T,$ and so $\operatorname{tr}(e_{i,j}) = \operatorname{tr}(e_j^T e_i) = \delta_{i,j}$ (that is, $1$ if $i=j$, otherwise $0$). Writing a general $n$ by $n$ matrix as a linear combination of these $e_{i,j},$ we see that any function satisfying the four properties must map a matrix to the sum of its diagonal elements.

Comment: Thanks for the help @RagibZaman!